# Ajax Post to Web Api (405 Method Not Allowed)

Tags: angularjs, ajax, asp.net-web-api, http-post

Having an issue when I am posting AngularJS data to Web API end point. From the client browser I receive:

```
405 (Method Not Allowed)
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
```

I have two separate projects which both run in localhost. On my Web Api I have set **EnableCors()** on config.

If I set content-type of the header to:

```
 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
```

Then it's able to hit my Web API endpoint. However my object argument is null. Could this be XML format rather than JSON? How do I go about resolving this?

Client side code:

```
 function signUp(data) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:15218/api/account/register',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            }

    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
}
```

Server Side Method signature:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Register(UserCommand command)
```

Comment: You need to enable cors on the server side

Comment: Yes I have and still not working

Comment: it seems not applied

Answer (score 0):

You can enable cors on the service by adding global.asax file

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, DELETE");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried changing the header content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8 but when it hits my api, the parameter result is null. Could this be because its setting to different format i.e. XML rather than JSON ?

Comment: it should be json

Comment: I have also done a simple test by only sending an int over and on the web api i explicitly placed [FromBody] but receive 0 rather than the actual number i set on client side.

Answer (score 0):

`Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405`

Before making the POST request you want to make, the browser is making an OPTIONS request asking for permission.

The server is responding to the OPTIONS request without a 200 response. The error message tells you that explicitly. (Maybe `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` cause the problem)

So before anything else, you must check for type of request method. If it is `OPTIONS` , pass 200 response code.

Comment: I have tried changing the header content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8 but when it hits my api, the paramter result is null. Could this be because its setting to different format i.e. XML rather than JSON ?